# Why do I get a missing quote error when using the following in a mapping using execute and normal?

Tags: key-bindings

The command is

```
nnoremap <leader>; :execute "normal! mqA;\<esc>`q"
```

If you then press `<leader>;`, you will `E114: Missing quote: "normal! mqA;\` followed by `E15: Invalid expression: "normal! mqA;\`. Why is this? The command works fine if input directly into the commandline.

The command adds a `;` at the end of the current line, without changing the cursors position.

I realise that I can just do `` nnoremap <leader>; mqA;<esc>`q `` which works, the question is why the above doesn't work, and what can be done to make it work in the execute-normal form.

My guess would be that some level of nested escaping is needed, but I couldn't find one that works.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to escape the `<` via `<lt>`:

```
nnoremap <leader>; :execute "normal! mqA;\<lt>esc>`q"<cr>
```

Note: added `<cr>` to execute the command as well.

However this can be simplified quite a bit:

```
nnoremap <leader>; mqA;<esc>`q
```

Using an expression mapping you can make your mapping conditional based on a trailing `;` character:

```
nnoremap <expr> <leader>; getline('.') =~ ';$' ? '' : "mqA;\<esc>`q"
```

For more help see:

```
:h <lt>
:h map-<expr>
```

Comment: In the vim documentation. see `:h <>`. The relevant part is: The <> notation uses <lt> to escape the special meaning of key names.  Using a
backslash also works, but only when 'cpoptions' does not include the 'B' flag. So if `B` flag is not in `cpotions`, you can use `\<Esc>` to represent the `<Esc>` key.

Answer (score 5):

You need to escape the `<ESC>` in command mode.  This is done by prefixing it with `<C-v>`.  You also need a trailing `<CR>` to actually run it.  Like this:

```
nnoremap <silent> <leader>; :execute "normal! mqA;<C-v><ESC>`q"<CR>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found that there are 3 ways to escape the  key:

1. `` nnoremap <silent> <leader>; :execute "normal! mqA;<C-v><esc>`q"<CR> ``
2. `` nnoremap <silent> <leader>; :execute "normal! mqA;\<lt>esc>`q"<CR> ``
3. `` nnoremap <silent> <leader>; :execute "normal! mqA;\e`q"<CR> ``

Similar for the Enter key (`<cr>`):

`<c-v><cr>` or `\<lt>cr>` or `\r`.

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]!