# Missing <c-q> when mapping Ex Command

Tags: key-bindings, gvim

I am using Vim 7.4 in Windows 7.

I am trying to map <kbd>F2</kbd> to the following ex-command,

```
execute "normal ggf\<tab>"| execute "normal \<c-q>G$d"| %s/ \+//g
```

using the following mapping command

```
:nmap <F2> :execute "normal ggf\<tab>" \| execute "normal \<c-q>G$d" \| :%s/ \+//g
```

but when I press <kbd>F2</kbd>, the following shows up

> `:execute "normal ggf\^I" | execute "normal \G$d" |%s/ \+//g`

The `<tab>` changes to `^I` and `<c-q>` disappears. How can I prevent
those changes to execute the original ex-command?

Update:

Note: `<c-q>` is the default visual block selection in Vim 7.4 in Windows.

Input and the result,
[image]

As you can see the image below `<c-q>` disappears,
[image]

Comment: I'm not sure what is your problem: `^I` is the key code of `<tab>` so it is normal that it appears like this (see [`:h i_CTRL-V`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/insert.txt.html#i_CTRL-V)) and I think the same happens to `<c-q>`. Now if your problem is that your command appears but is not executed, it is because you didn't put `<CR>` at the end of the mapping which correspond to pressing `Enter` after you wrote your command.

Comment: Thank you @statox I realized that `<tab>` is same as `^I` but I was unaware of the `<CR>`. Unfortunately it still doesn't work. I get a **E488 Trailing Error** when executing `:nunmap <F2> :execute "normal ggf\<tab>"|execute "normal \<c-q>G$d"|%s/ \+//g<CR>` and when I execute `nmap <F2> :execute "normal ggf\<tab>"|execute "normal \<c-q>G$d"<CR>` I get **E121: Undefined variable: CR E15: Invalid Expression "normal\<c-q>G$d"**
Note: <c-q> is used for visual block selection

Comment: The trailing error is because you only need `nunmap <F2>` if you want to remove the mapping from the key, no need to specify the expression of the mapping. For the second error I'm not sure but why do you use `<c-q>` for visual block? You can use `<c-v>` and if you use `<c-q>` because you remapped `<c-v>` then use `normal!` in your expression so that your mapping are not used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured out the reason based on another vi stackexchange answer. [Link](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/3721/why-do-i-get-a-missing-quote-error-when-using-the-following-in-a-mapping-using-e).

Apparently the character `<` in `<c-q>` needs to be replaced by `<lt>`, though I do not know why but it solves the current problem. So the new mapping would be:

```
:nmap <F2> :execute "normal ggf\<tab>" \| execute "normal \<lt>c-q>G$d" \| :%s/ \+//g
```

Input:
[image]

Result:
[image]

And as per @statox's comment, `<cr>` needs to be added to the end of the mapping to actually execute the command.

So the final mapping would be:

```
:nmap <F2> :execute "normal ggf\<tab>" \| execute "normal \<lt>c-q>G$d" \| :%s/ \+//g<cr>
```